# Are ambient noises useful for keeping the dog calm while I'm away?

Tags: dogs, health

I live in an apartment and when I'm away or busy doing work in another room, I feel bad for the dog because there is nothing really for him to do. He doesn't have much interest in his toy (I should find some new ones) and he doesn't have  I know it would bug me to be locked inside for most of the day in a quiet room, but I also know dogs are not humans. Should I leave the TV on for him or put some ambient noise on the speakers? If so, what ambient noises are good? Suggestions?

Comment: Try also to "rotate" the toys, have a few but don't make them all available at the same time, change every few days.

Comment: That's a great idea! It makes perfect sense since he only seems to be interested in something if he can't have it. Or if he hasn't had it in a while.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it will help. My dog gets annoyed very fast, so I leave the radio on, and leave him a ball(not a tennis ball, but a hard ball, which keeps him busy). Have you tried already those sticks, things he can chew on? Search for a none dangerous toy that he likes. Bored dogs get frustrated.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try raw hide or something I think. I've tried downloading some Youtube "dog music" and it seemed to work great!

Comment: @Klik Try a bully stick, but make sure it's made in the USA. Deer antlers are great, too. Make sure with both of these products you keep a close eye on him for a while before leaving him alone with them. If your dog is really into the deer antler, he may make it so small that he can choke. With the split ones, it's easier to break off pieces, too. Bowser broke off a few pieces and later he induced-regurgitated... so you always want to make sure that they're fine with the product before leaving them unattended.

Comment: Why is it important that it be "made in the USA", @Jeremy?

Comment: @Ingo I'm sorry, I assumed that the OP was from the US. The main thing is you don't want to get from risky sources like China where there have been known to be diseases carried in the raw meats.

Comment: @Ingo : one Pets question explaining some problems with China-sourced treats: http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/906/how-can-i-identify-and-get-more-information-about-poisoned-jerky-treats

Comment: @Jeremy I will look for one for sure. That's a good tip since I'm not too familiar with dog chew things.